# Template argument deduction/substitution failed, when using typename argument

Tags: c++, function, templates, parameters, traits

I have the following code, which defines a template struct `W` that exports a type `T` that's based on the template argument to `W`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <unsigned N>
struct Y {};

template <unsigned N>
struct W {
  using T = Y<N>;
};
```

I then defined this template function that looks at this type `T`:

```
template <unsigned N>
void foo (const typename W<N>::T& in) {
  //--
}
```

The problem here is that if I try calling this function from `main` using one of the types exported as `T`, it doesn't compile. For example, if I write

```
int main() {
  Y<2> y;
  foo(y);
  return 0;
}
```

I get a compiler error that says

> template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>
> couldn't deduce template parameter

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the C++ compiler can't figure this out has to do with template specialization. For example, suppose that you specialize the `W` struct template like this:

```
template <> struct W<137> {
    using T = Y<0>; // Not Y<137>
};
```

Now, suppose that you call `foo`, passing in a `Y<0>` as the argument. What should the compiler deduce as the numeric value of `N`? It could be zero, since `W<0>` defines `T` as `Y<0>`. But it could just as easily be 137, since `W<137>` defines `T` as `Y<0>` as well.

More generally, C++ will never try to deduce the type of a template argument to an *outer* template based on one of the *inner* types, for precisely the reason shown above.